# React setState dynamically using string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, tslint

How can I set and existing state field dynamically in a React component?

My current tries lead to the following approach, but it does not work in TypeScript:

```
export interface MaskCompanyDetailState {
    fieldId: number;
}

export class MaskCompanyDetail extends React.Component<MaskCompanyDetailProps, MaskCompanyDetailState> {

    public constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        // Set field defaults.
        this.state = {
            fieldId: 0,
        };
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        const myField: string = 'fieldId';
        const myVal: number = 123;
        this.setState({[myField]: myVal});
        this.setState({myField: myVal});
    }
}
```

Error message from TSLint for `this.setState({[myField]: myVal});`:

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MaskCompanyDetailState | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Readonly) => MaskCompanyDetailState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.
>     Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick': fieldId, fieldCompanyName, fieldStreetName, fieldStreetNumber, and 4 more.ts(2345)

Error message from TSLint for `this.setState({myField: myVal});`:

> Argument of type '{ myField: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MaskCompanyDetailState | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Readonly) => MaskCompanyDetailState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myField' does not exist in type 'MaskCompanyDetailState | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Readonly) => MaskCompanyDetailState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.ts(2345)

There is already a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409931/react-typescript-and-a-setstate-name-value-error), but I don't see how to apply the suggested `IState` interface.

Comment: do you want to add a property to the object ? or else do you want to use  value of `myField` variable to dynamically set property name ?

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the `myField` key? Kind of defeats the point of a computed property, `{['myField']: 123}` is the same as `{myField: 123}`, which I assume isn't what you want to do, I'm guessing `myField` is a variable, in which case it should be `{[myField]: 123}`

Comment: I have updated the post by specifying the initial question and by providing more code.

Comment: Tangentially related: "TSLint" refers to a now-deprecated separate tool. You probably meant "TypeScript" there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following field to `MaskCompanyDetailState` interface -

```
[key: string]: any;
```

i.e.,

```
interface MaskCompanyDetailState {
    ... // existing fields
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

It means that you are allowing any property which has a key of type `string` and value of `any` type to be set in your state. 
This is what your linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409931/react-typescript-and-a-setstate-name-value-error) says. This is an example of [`Index Signature`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) which is a feature of Typescript.

It's not really recommended, because it affects readability of your code in the long run and other people in your team may abuse it. But I am not aware of any other solutions to your predicament other than to rethink your design.

Comment: Is it possible to set it `readonly` so that it is possible to read/write existing field, but to block the possibility to create new fields at runtime?

Comment: The `[key: string]: any;` part is an Index Signature, and not really a property. I have edited my answer to include a link for more information. While you can set it to `readonly`, when you execute `this.setState({[myField]: myVal});` in your code, you are actually creating new fields/properties in the state at runtime. There is no way around that.

Comment: `readonly` means you can only create(and mutate in case of arrays) a property on the state. AFAIK, there is no way to stop people from creating new fields at runtime with an `Index Signature`. My suggestion would be to declare all possible fields in `MaskCompanyDetailState`, but mark them as optional, instead of using an `Index Signature`.